# android play store update failed after migrating to android 33

Tags: android, google-play

I have migrated android api level from android 31 to 33, while updating 31 to 33 i have upgraded gradle distribution and some android libraries.We are generating builds through appcenter with same release configuration.Whatever builds i generate through appcenter can override but from play store i am not able to update, i am getting update option but after downloading it is showing can't install.

```
 ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip
```

getting error package conflict while overriding local build on top of playstore build.